# want to print the selected column of sql table queried through html form

Tags: php, html, sql

i want to print only selected columns from mysql table on website which are query through html form.
$column[] store the columns which user want to see on the web.
So how to select the particular columns from a mysql table.

inside the php file

```
<?php
@ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'passwd', 'myDatabase');   
$column = $_POST['columns']; // column passed through html   
$query = "select *  from primers" ;   
$result = $db->query($query);   
$num_results = $result->num_rows;   
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)     
{    
$field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td>$cell</td>";
echo "</tr>\n";
}

?>
```

now in place of * i want to select the column name which are specified in $column array.

Help me.Thank you

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: @Shnugo `$db = new mysql()i`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Yes. should have seen that :-D

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
$query = "select " . (empty($column) ? '*' : implode(', ', $column)) . " from primers";
```